# In Sinatra, share code with between routes and rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

We would like to have some maintenance tasks that leverage code used in routes or helpers.

What is the best way to accomplish this in a modular Sinatra app?

For example, we have a mailer. We would like it to be invoked from a route. But we also want to send regularly scheduled emails from a rake task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor the common code into a module (or a class) into a different source file:

```
# mailer.rb

module Mailer
  def common_method0
  end

  def common_method1
  end
end
```

In your Sinatra app, require mailer.rb and mix in your module where it's needed:

```
require_relative 'mailer'

# ...

helpers do
  include Mailer

  # other helpers
end
```

In your rake tasks, do the same:

```
# Rakefile

require_relative 'mailer'
include Mailer

task :mailer do
  common_method0

  # ...
end
```